# realloc: Segmentation fault

Tags: c, memory, memory-management

Take the following code,which is in `a.c` :

```
struct header {
    char **name;
};
int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char **p;
    struct header h;
    char tmp[10];
    memset(&h, 0, sizeof(h));

    for(i=1;i<10;i++){
        sprintf(tmp, "name%d", i); 
        p = realloc(h.name, sizeof(char*)*i);
        printf("h->name=%p, p=%p\n", h.name, p); 
        h.name = p;
        h.name[i-1] = malloc(100);
        strncpy(h.name+i-1, tmp, strlen(tmp));
        printf("h->name=%s\n", h.name+i-1);
    }   
    return 0;
}
```

after i `gcc a.c` and `./a.out`,following error happends:

`Segmentation fault`
I have no any idea about this,what exactly this happen?

EDIT1:
found the qustion!
`strncpy(h.name+i-1, tmp, strlen(tmp))` should `strncpy(h.name[i - 1], tmp, strlen(tmp) + 1)` and this qustion can be found through `gcc warnings:/usr/include/string.h:131:14: note: expected ‘char * __restrict__’ but argument is of type ‘char **’`,so silly! thanks to everyone!

Answer (score 2):

`strncpy(h.name+i-1, tmp, strlen(tmp));` doesn't null terminate the destination string. It may be that the next `printf()` crashes trying to print it.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect you're compiling on a 64 bit system, and don't have:

```
#include <stdlib.h>
```

at the top of your file. You should get a warning about this when you compile:

> incompatible implicit declaration of built-in function ‘malloc’

As Michael Burr points out, you're also not terminating the string correctly.

You should be able to find out where it is crashing by compiling with `-g` and running it through a debugger (eg gdb).

Comment: You  can if it's a null pointer.  The `memset()` will do that (yes, I know technically copying zero bits doesn't necessarily result in a null pointer, but I'm pretty sure that's not the problem here).

Comment: @tim there's not point,see `man realloc`:realloc() changes the size of the memory block pointed to by ptr to size bytes.  The contents will be unchanged to the minimum of the old and new sizes;  newly
       allocated memory will be uninitialized.  If ptr is NULL, then the call is equivalent to malloc(size), for all values of size; if size is equal to zero, and ptr
       is not NULL, then the call is equivalent to free(ptr).  Unless ptr is NULL, it must have been returned by an earlier call to malloc(), calloc()  or  realloc().
       If the area pointed to was moved, a free(ptr) is done.

Comment: Updated with a different issue.

Comment: answer was changed and comments don't reflect how it currently stands

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that your strncpy is only strlen(tmp) so if temp is name5, strlen(tmp) == 5, which doesn't copy the NULL that your sprintf put on.  You need to do strlen(tmp)+1 to copy in the NULL.

http://linux.die.net/man/3/strncpy

Also, it's odd that h.name is a double pointer to char.  If it should be a string, it should just be a char *.  It is then weird that you're only mallocing space for your array of single pointers to one entry.

Comment: He's progressively allocating an array of strings, adding one string in each loop iteration. And I assume you mean to suggest `strlen(tmp)+1`.

Comment: @MichaelBurr  haha, yes (updated).  But the realloc on h.name throws away the previous mallocs doesn't it?  and not in a good way but in a memory-leaking sort of way?

Comment: @MichaelBurr ah, I didn't know how realloc works.  It's silly to do it this way and may result in a lot of copying memory around depending on fragmentation, but it does keep the contents around.

Answer (score 0):

'\0' of a string is not the whole thing.although you need

```
strlen(tmp)+1
```

but the main error is that you didn't dereference your char** pointer like this:

```
strncpy(*(h.name+i-1), tmp, strlen(tmp)+1);
printf("h->name=%s\n", *(h.name+i-1));
```

this below will work, and I have tested it by my gcc:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

struct header {
char **name;
};

int main(void)
{
    int i=0;
    char **p;
    struct header h;
    char tmp[10];
    memset(&h, 0, sizeof(h));

    for(i=1;i<10;i++){
        sprintf(tmp, "name%d", i);
        //printf("tmp:%s\n",tmp);
        p = realloc(h.name, sizeof(char*)*i);
        printf("h->name=%p, p=%p\n", h.name, p);
        if(p==NULL) {
            printf("realloc failed.\n");
            return -1;
        }
        h.name = p;
        h.name[i-1] = (char *)malloc(100);
        strncpy(*(h.name+i-1), tmp, strlen(tmp)+1);
        printf("h->name=%s\n", *(h.name+i-1));
    }   
    return 0;
}
```